# setting Array in model-class from NSArrayController

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsarraycontroller

How do I set the array in my model-class `ValueItem` with the content of an `NSArrayController`in my AppDelegate class:

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
{
    ValueItem *vi;
}
```

and:

```
@implementation AppDelegate
{

    ValueItem *array = [[ValueItem alloc]init];
    [array setValueArray:[outArrayController arrangedObjects]];

    NSArray *testArray2 = vi.valueArray; // !!!getter or setter doesn't work!!!
    NSLog(@"test array 2 is:%@", testArray2);
}
```

`NSLog` returns `NULL`. What do I miss here?
(valueArray is initialized with `@property` and `@synthesize`)

ValueItem.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface ValueItem : NSObject
{
    NSNumber *nomValue;
    NSNumber *tolerancePlus;
    NSNumber *toleranceMinus;
    NSMutableArray *valueArray;
}
@property (readwrite, copy) NSNumber *nomValue;
@property (readwrite, copy) NSNumber *tolerancePlus;
@property (readwrite, copy) NSNumber *toleranceMinus;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *valueArray;

@end
```

ValueItem.m:

```
#import "ValueItem.h"
@implementation ValueItem

@synthesize nomValue, tolerancePlus, toleranceMinus;
@synthesize valueArray;

-(NSString*)description
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"nomValue is: %@ | tolerancePlus is: %@ | toleranceMinus is: %@", nomValue, tolerancePlus, toleranceMinus];

}
@end
```

Comment: Need to see your `ValueItem` code. Also what is output of `NSLog(@"%@", [outArrayController arrangedObjects]);`?

Comment: Hello Michael, thanks for your reply. Reading the arrayControllers content with `NSLog(@"%@", [outArrayController arrangedObjects]);` works fine and returns the content as expected. I added the `ValueItem` code.

Comment: Check the output of `NSLog(@"%@", vi.valueArray);`

Comment: Hi Michael it returns still `NULL`. The code is inside an action (button) method. Is that important for the "code flow"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**: Need to make sure you're dealing with the AppDelegate's `vi` property:

```
// We need to make sure we're manipulating the AppDelegate's vi property!
self.vi = [[ValueItem alloc]init];
[vi setValueArray:[outArrayController arrangedObjects]];

NSArray *testArray2 = vi.valueArray; // !!!getter or setter doesn't work!!!
NSLog(@"test array 2 is:%@", testArray2);
```

---

**Explanation** :
On the first two lines you were manipulating the `array` `ValueItem` variable, then attempting to set `testArray2` to the value of the uninitialized `vi` `ValueItem` variable.

```
// This is a new variable, unrelated to AppDelegate.vi
ValueItem *array = [[ValueItem alloc]init];
[array setValueArray:[outArrayController arrangedObjects]];

// Here, AppDelegate.vi hasn't been initialized, so valueArray *will* be null!
NSArray *testArray2 = vi.valueArray; 
NSLog(@"test array 2 is:%@", testArray2);
```

Comment: Hello Michael, it still returns `NULL` but I'm not sure if i use the right getter method with `NSArray *testArray2 = vi.valueArray;` and     `NSLog(@"test array 2 is:%@", testArray2);`

Comment: `vi.valueArray` should work. Check my comment on your question.

Comment: Awesome, it worked. Thanks. But I don't get the difference. Why do I need to use the different setter method for the array? To set the model entities I use `ValueItem *newItem = [[ValueItem alloc]init];` and `[newItem setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[_inputNomValue doubleValue]] forKey:@"nomValue"];`

Comment: Because you were trying to set `testArray2` to the value of `vi.valueArray`, which had not been set yet. Instead you were initializing `array`, but not using it on the aforementioned line.

Comment: Ah, I got it. A big Thank you to you. Not everybody is staying with a greenhorn like me until the end. The best for you! You helped me a lot.

Comment: When I started learning Cocoa I found it very confusing, and due to my inexperience the docs were useless. SO + the Cocoa devs list were lifesavers. This site is for all programmers, regardless of experience!

Comment: Trust me not everybody is having that mindset. And I got my reputations back which I lost with angry comments couple days ago. Awesome! What are the Cocoa devs lists? Where can I find those?

Comment: Most people should, you can flag nasty comments. Cocoa dev list is the official Apple Cocoa mailing list: https://lists.apple.com/mailman/listinfo/cocoa-dev good for asking questions or just reading.